# Android Studio failed to load image file

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native, android-emulator, virtual-device-manager

I cannot run any virtual device on Android studio. Every time I get black screen and error as shown on the picture: [screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PhRem.png)
.
Week ago everything worked properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can create emulator without device frame. Like this 
[image]